# Attach sound file from gallery in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Is it possible to access sound files gallery just like image gallery in my iOS app, I have tried searching on net but have not found any good content about it.

Comment: Did the solution given below worked for you, since the Question has been asked 3 years from now,will it work today?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the [AddMusic](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AddMusic/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008845-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_9) sample application from Apple to see how its done...

Comment: is it also possible to send these files to server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can upload it to server. Use below code :

When you select a song from picker

```
- (void)mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection 
{
    MPMediaItem *song = nil ;
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    if ([mediaItemCollection count] < 1) 
    {
        return;
    }
    [song release];
    song = [[[mediaItemCollection items] objectAtIndex:0] retain];

    //song.accessibilityHin

    [self uploadMusicFile:song];
}

- (void) uploadMusicFile:(MPMediaItem *)song
{
    // Init audio with playback capability
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

    NSURL *assetURL = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    AVURLAsset *songAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:assetURL options:nil];
 // to get uniqe time interval
    [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    // convert this ti string
    NSTimeInterval seconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSString *intervalSeconds = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f",seconds];

    AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset: songAsset                                                                       presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];

    exporter.outputFileType = @"public.mpeg-4";

    NSString *exportFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[DOCUMENTS_FOLDER stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp4",intervalSeconds]]];


    NSURL *exportURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportFile] retain];
    exporter.outputURL = exportURL; 

    [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
     ^{
         NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:exportURL];

         // Here your upload code 
     }];
}
```